# Performance testing a deployed servlet application?

Tags: java, servlets, jmeter, performance-testing, requestdispatcher

Currently I have a servlet based application that retrieves data from an archived database and sends it back to the client as an XML over HTTP.

I want to create an "X" test client to test my database retrieval servlet for the following:

- Min HTTP response time
- Max HTTP response time
- Errors received from server

The application is almost in deployment phase of development , however I need a test client that I can use after its deployed to check the application is performing as it should or if I need to do maintenance in its environment (e.g. reindex database) say after 6 months.

I am wanting it to generate thousands of HTTP requests (spam) the application.

So far I  can think of two ways to do this:

1. Multithreaded java console app that sends multiple HTTP requests 
       simultaneously over multiple threads from my computer.
2. A separate java servlet that sends HTTPS requests simultaneously from one server to another over multiple threads.

I am thinking that a servlet test application would be the best for the job as its already multithreaded by default.

How would I implement this though, do I just use the **requestDispatcher** class to call to another servlet or is there a better way?

Any advice welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you look into [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/). It is a great tool for simulating loads on web applications/servlets (and other). You can define (branching) workflows, several threads, thread groups, delays, ramp up times etc.

I think it would fit your option 1) criteria perfectly.

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks for this, it seems a bit complicated to operate. It has a lot of features. Perhaps a bit overkill for what I am needing.

Comment: Fair enough, your call :-) It *is* a very versatile tool, but you don't need to use all the facilities... There is a good online manual/tutorial with a lot of screenshot, eg. http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html -- I still think you should give it a shot before coding yourself. Cheers,

Comment: That link is much better than the main tutorial , thanks @Anders!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can try [apache benching tool (ab)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html). It's simple and useful. You just need to specify client threads number, total request count, and the URL you want to test, then you can get what you need.

Comment: Thanks for this also, but sadly I am using an Oracle web server. However I will keep this in mind for other projects that use LAMP. :)